# Найти подлежащее

Tags: синтаксис, подлежащее

У  него  не  было  никаких  сомнений.

Answer (score 5):

Это **безличное предложение**, такой тип предложений называют отрицательно-бытийными (слова "нет, не было" в роли сказуемого).

**Грамматическое подлежащее отсутствует,** но существительное в Р.п. является обязательным структурным элементом отрицательно-бытийного предложения  и обозначает семантический субъект.

Парный вариант: Были сомнения. ― Не было сомнений.